# asp.net vb Point to a row in a gridview with code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If you bind a datatable to a gridview control, how do you then select a row with code in the gridview, to point the curser to that particular row. My datatable has one  column with KeyValues and another column with names.

Thx in advance.

Comment: You can set the SelectedIndex of the GridView to the index of the row. You mean that you want to find the index corresponding to a specific key value, right?

Comment: Here is a way to do it with a key value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350453/how-to-set-selected-row-in-asp-net-gridview-based-on-datakey.